# What is the difference between a customizable framework and a library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with [SlateJS](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate) and I'm wondering if it's rather a library than a framework, the author himself describes SlateJS as:

> A completely customizable framework for building rich text editors

Okay so it's a library at the end ? ReactJS is also a completely customizable creator of web application in a some point of view _

Just to review theses concepts, 
any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: Thanks Amy for your comment but I asked this question in the specific scope of a "completely customizable framework" that made me wondering, by the end of the way it allows to underline that even a completely customizable framework like SlateJS is still a framework because of its summoning as a completely blueprinted utils, even being fully customizable IMHO

Comment: "completely customizable" framework is just marketing-speak.  It isn't a context.

Comment: you have tested SlateJS to say that I suppose

Comment: No, but I don't need to to understand the difference between a framework and a library, and that "completely customizable" is not a technical term.

Comment: Some other people could need to make a difference to better understand among them I am, be tolerant with the people less smart than you ;), that said, thanks for the link, very usefull effetcively

Answer (score 3):

A library is a bunch of functions / classes grouped together. A framework is a bunch of functions / classes grouped together that helps you structure your code. Every framework is a library.

Comment: hmm the data structure so, very interesting remarks